# How can I connect to Facebook chat using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, facebook, chat

How can I connect to Facebook chat using C# or Visual Basic?

Comment: `-1`; .NET is not a language. By the way, try inspecting the code to Empathy; it supports Facebook chat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using XMPP (formerly named Jabber).

Heres a list of XMPP (Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol) Libraries written in C# .NET

> **C# / .NET / Mono**
>
> - [agsXMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.de/index.php?page=agsxmpp-sdk)
> - [IP*Works Internet Toolkit](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/)
> - [jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/)
> - [MatriX](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix.html)
> - [SoapBox Studio](http://www.coversant.net/product/studio-overview.aspx)
> - [Ubeity](http://ubietyxmpp.ca/)

*Sources:
[xmpp.org](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#csharp),
[wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP)*

Comment: which one is the best and most simple?

Comment: It's hard to say, really, but I have heard some good things about jabber-net. You would have to find out for yourself.

Comment: This answer is obsolete as of May 2015